# Sum specific columns on sql / pl

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that return this:

```
id | task | company | percent
1  | a    | abc     | 33.20
2  | b    | abc     | 13.70
3  | c    | xpt     | 33.20
4  | d    | xpt     | 20.10
```

I want to get a query that return something like this:

```
id | company | percent
1  | abc     | 46.90
3  | xpt     | 53.30
```

Is it possible? how can I do that?

Comment: [***Have you tried anyhting?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: select id, company, percent from ... 
post the query you are using now

Comment: You need to group by company, but if you really want only the first ID of a grouping, that will get more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [group by](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) with "min" and "sum" aggregates should work

```
select 
    min(id) as id, 
    company, 
    sum("percent") as percent 
from 
    [yourtable] 
group by 
    company
```

As StuartLC noted, "percent" is a reserved word and must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two aggregates with a group by on the non-aggregated company column - one for the MIN(ID) and the other for the SUM(percent)

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id,
       company, 
       SUM("percent") AS Percent
FROM SomeTable 
GROUP BY company;
```

Note that `percent` is reserved and needs to be escaped. [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce38d/1)

Comment: Good call on escaping the percent keyword. I missed that.